# PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

Tags: python-3.x

Actually, am trying to tokenize the pdf file into a sentence, firstly I used `pypdf2` but am facing the loss of data and improper format issue. so I tried with ocr but while converting pdf to image am facing poppler issue
 can anyone help me out to fix this issue

```
pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file, 600)
```

---

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py in _page_count(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path)
    239             env["LD_LIBRARY_PATH"] = poppler_path + ":" + env.get("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "")
--> 240         proc = Popen(command, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    241 

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    776         except:

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
   1177                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
-> 1178                                          startupinfo)
   1179             finally:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
PDFInfoNotInstalledError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-3c78fc8271dd> in <module>
----> 1 pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file, 600)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py in convert_from_path(pdf_path, dpi, output_folder, first_page, last_page, fmt, thread_count, userpw, use_cropbox, strict, transparent, single_file, output_file, poppler_path)
     52     """
     53 
---> 54     page_count = _page_count(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path=poppler_path)
     55 
     56     # We start by getting the output format, the buffer processing function and if we need pdftocairo

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py in _page_count(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path)
    242         out, err = proc.communicate()
    243     except:
--> 244     raise PDFInfoNotInstalledError('Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?')
    245 
    246     try:

PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count.
```

Is poppler installed and in PATH?

Answer (score 7):

my code works fine when I install this code below in my Anaconda prompt, check if it works for you too!

conda install -c conda-forge poppler

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still has this error on Windows, I solved the problem by:

1. Download the Latest binary of Poppler for Windows from [Poppler Windows](https://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/)
2. Unzip it into C drive like C:\poppler-0.68.0
3. Specify the Poppler path in environment variables

[Poppler path in env variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPkvD.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy if you download the poppler.
https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/
After extracting it and move into program files
Finally set environment variable to poppler bin folder.
[ System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Add your poppler bin to Path as a new one]
Documentation :
https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/