# "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?"

Tags: python-3.x, poppler, pdf2image

I am trying to import pdf2image but end up to this error "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?"

I am using Anaconda 2.1.4 and Jupyter Notebook 6.4.5

Comment: Well... is poppler installed and in PATH?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Poppler in path for pdf2image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481088/poppler-in-path-for-pdf2image)

Comment: Or this? [PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57535731/pdfinfonotinstallederror-unable-to-get-page-count-is-poppler-installed-and-in)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got the same in Google Colab and yes poppler was installed. What does PATH even mean in that context?

Comment: Any solution for Windows?

Answer (score 2):

you have to install

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

Comment: Any solution for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

FOR MAC, if you have brew installed, that is the way to go.

`brew install poppler`

for Homebrew installation please follow [here](https://brew.sh/).

Comment: Any solution for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

for linux you can use (for Colab also same will work)

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

for windows you can use anaconda

```
conda install -c conda-forge poppler
```